# При работе с бинарными файлами .exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова СИ

Tags: c, файлы, потоки-данных, fopen

Я вызываю две эти функции(это реализовано в main): сначала добавляю данные в файл, затем считываю в массив структур и вывожу. Первая функция работает, а при вызове второй функции - "срабатывание точки останова" при присвоении переменной fp указателя на поток - при вызове функции fopen(). Помогите разобраться с проблемой не понимаю, где ошибка. Может быть это из-за глобальных переменных?
Функция number_input просто присваивает значение по указателю.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct member { // структура члена сборной команды по футболу
    char full_name[60]; // ФИО
    char club[30];
    char role[12]; // goalkeeper, defender, midfielder, striker
    int age;
    int matches;
    int goals_scored;
};

int contain_latin_letters(char str[50], int len) { // функция проверяет, является ли символ допустимым для использования (латинские буквы и цифры)
    char aval[] = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM "; // массив допустимых символов
    int aval_length = strlen(aval); // подсчитываем длину строки aval c помощью функции из библиотеки string.h
    int f = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aval_length; i++) {
            if (aval[i] == str[j]) // если находим совпадение, то возвращаем 1 (правда - символ является допустимым)
                f++;
        }
    }
    if(f == len)
        return 1;
    return 0; // если не будет возвращена 1, то возвращаем 0 (ложь)
}

void number_input(char str[256], int* p) { // функция присвоит необходимое(числовое) значение переменной в основной функции, находящейся по адресу(2-ой аргумент)
    char string[256];
    printf("%s", str);
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    while (sscanf(string, "%i", p) != 1) {
        printf("Incorrect input, try again!! %s", str);
        fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    }
}

FILE* fp;
struct member* arr;
int arr_len = 0;

void add_data() {
    fp = fopen("database.bin", "wb");
    arr_len++;
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(struct member*) * arr_len);
    printf("  Input information about new member:");
    do {
        printf("\nFull name - ");
        getchar();
        gets(arr[arr_len - 1].full_name);
    } while (!contain_latin_letters(arr[arr_len - 1].full_name, strlen(arr[arr_len - 1].full_name)));
    do {
        printf("Club - ");
        gets(arr[arr_len - 1].club);
    } while (!contain_latin_letters(arr[arr_len - 1].club, strlen(arr[arr_len - 1].club)));
    do {
        printf("Role (goalkeeper, defender, midfielder, striker) - ");
        gets(arr[arr_len - 1].role);
    } while (!(!strcmp(arr[arr_len - 1].role, "goalkeeper") || !strcmp(arr[arr_len - 1].role, "defender") || !strcmp(arr[arr_len - 1].role, "midfielder") || !strcmp(arr[arr_len - 1].role, "striker")));
    number_input("Age of member - ", &arr[arr_len - 1].age);
    number_input("Number of matches played for team - ", &arr[arr_len - 1].matches);
    number_input("Number of scored goals - ", &arr[arr_len - 1].goals_scored);

    char* c = (char*)arr; // устанавливаем указатель на начало структуры
    // посимвольно записываем в файл структуру
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(struct member) * arr_len; i++)
    {
        putc(*c++, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void output_database() {
    fp = fopen("database.bin", "rb");

    char* c = (char*)arr;
    // считываем посимвольно из файла
    int i;
    while ((i = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        *c = i;
        c++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++)
        printf("%s   %s   %s   %d   %d   %d\n", arr[i].full_name, arr[i].club, arr[i].role, arr[i].age, arr[i].matches, arr[i].goals_scored);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void) {
    int f;
    printf("\tMenue:\n1 -> Add data\n2 -> Output database\n0 -> End process\n");
    do {
    place:;
        printf("\nInput number of the option from menue: ");
        scanf("%d", &f);
        switch (f) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            add_data();
            break;
        case 2:
            output_database();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input, make it again!! ");
            goto place;
            break;
        }
    } while (f != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: - "не понимаю, где ошибка." - Где ошибка - Вы сами сказали. На вызове *fopen()*. А вот в чём ошибка, я тоже не понимаю. Пока не увижу **текст сообщения об ошибке**. Увы, я не телепат.

Comment: У вас UB, после закрытия файла вы не имеете права снова использовать тот же указатель. Поместите его в стек!

Comment: Я убрал глобальную переменную (FILE* fp;), и в каждой функции сделал разные указатели на потоки, но исключение "Project1.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова." всё равно срабатывает во второй функции при открытии потока.

Comment: при вызове output_database у Вас указатель arr может вообще никуда не указывать. Память под него не выделяете.  Вот оно и прибежало.  Покажите весь код - тогда можно будет точнее сказать

Comment: Но эта ошибка может появиться, если вызвать функцию output_database() первой, но у меня ошибка срабатывает в ней после вызова add_data(), поэтому под массив arr выделена память

Answer (score 0):

я решил для начала просто минимальной правкой заставить работать код (для тех, кто решил минусовать - листайте дальше, там будет лучше)

```c
  void output_database() {
      fp = fopen("database.bin", "rb");

  // возмьем размер массива
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      size_t sz = ftell(fp);
      // размер файла должен быть кратен размеру структуры
      if (sz % sizeof(struct member) != 0)
      {
          // упс
          fclose(fp);
      }
      // теперь мы можем выставить этот самый размер!
      arr_len = sz / sizeof(struct member);
      rewind(fp); // отмотаем на начало файла
      arr = malloc(sz); // выделим достаточно места
      char* c = (char*)arr;
      // считываем посимвольно из файла
      int i;
      while ((i = getc(fp)) != EOF)
      {
          *c = i;
          c++;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++)
         printf("%s   %s   %s   %d   %d   %d\n", arr[i].full_name, arr[i].club, arr[i].role, arr[i].age, arr[i].matches, arr[i].goals_scored);
      fclose(fp);
  }
```

все, можно запускать, оно уже выводит данные. Но давайте посмотрим на это неподобство - чтения файла посимвольно. Зачем, если можно прочитать буквально одной строкой.

```
fread(arr, sizeof(struct member), arr_len, fp);
```

И все. Правда есть ещё странная запись. Давайте перепишем запись как нужно.

```
fwrite(arr, sizeof(struct member), arr_len, fp);
```

и никаких циклов. Мало того, что это быстрее, так ещё и понятнее.

В результате функция превратилась вот в такое

```c
  void output_database() {
      int record_size = sizeof(struct member);
      FILE* fp = fopen("database.bin", "rb");

  // возьмем размер массива
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      size_t sz = ftell(fp);
      if (sz % record_size != 0)
      {
          // упс
          fclose(fp);
      }
      int arr_len = sz / record_size;
      rewind(fp);
      struct member* arr = malloc(sz);

      fread(arr, record_size, arr_len, fp);
      // вывод
      for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++)
          printf("%s   %s   %s   %d   %d   %d\n", arr[i].full_name, arr[i].club, arr[i].role, arr[i].age, arr[i].matches, arr[i].goals_scored);
      fclose(fp);
      free(arr);
  }
```

В коде ещё куча страшного, но это тема отдельных разговоров. Например, сигнатуру этой функции `void number_input(char str[256], int* p)` лучше исправить где то на такую

```
void number_input(char* str, int* p)
```